# re-trying fetch() calls in the middle of a .then() chain

Tags: javascript

I rarely write JS, and not very good at it. I know what I am trying to do, but not clear on how to write it.

I'm not used to working with async network requests

```
var currentURL = window.location.href.split("/profile/")[1].split("?")[0]
fetch("https://www.website.com/cap/people/profileExportPdf/20200913.pdf?memberIds="+currentURL+"&origin=profile&trackingSearchId=db44af3b-aade-4624-b8f7-6e780bcb8912%2CZbGp")
.then(resp => {return resp.json()})
.then(data => {
    console.log(data.id)
    canID = data.id
    return canID
})
.then(canID => {
    console.log(canID)
    //I need to keep re-trying this URL until it returns back as Ready
    fetch("https://www.website.com/cap/people/printStateAjax?id="+canID)
    .then(resp=>resp.json())
    .then(data=>{
        console.log(data)
        if(data.msg == "Ready") {
            // if this returns not ready, under the else statement, have it retry
            console.log('ready')
            fetch("https://www.website.com/cap/people/streamPdf/"+canID)
            .then(resp => {return resp.blob()})
            .then(blob => {
                const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                const a = document.createElement('a');
                a.style.display = 'none';
                a.href = url;
                a.download = 'file_name';
                document.body.appendChild(a);
                a.click();
                window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url)
            })
        } else {
            // What do I put here to retry the fetch to /printStateAJX?id=
        }
    })    
})
```

I know I should break it out as a seperate function and just keep retrying that function until data.msg returns "Ready", but I'm unsure how to write it

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should "break apart" the promise where you make the check and create a function that will recursively call itself until the base case (`data.msg === 'Ready'`) succeeds.

```
var currentURL = window.location.href.split("/profile/")[1].split("?")[0]
fetch("https://www.website.com/cap/people/profileExportPdf/20200913.pdf?memberIds="+currentURL+"&origin=profile&trackingSearchId=db44af3b-aade-4624-b8f7-6e780bcb8912%2CZbGp")
.then(resp => {return resp.json()})
.then(data => {
    console.log(data.id)
    canID = data.id
    return canID
})
.then(recursiveFunc)

function recursiveFunc(canID) {
    console.log(canID)
    //I need to keep re-trying this URL until it returns back as Ready
    fetch("https://www.website.com/cap/people/printStateAjax?id="+canID)
    .then(resp=>resp.json())
    .then(data=>{
        console.log(data)
        if(data.msg == "Ready") {
            // if this returns not ready, under the else statement, have it retry
            console.log('ready')
            fetch("https://www.website.com/cap/people/streamPdf/"+canID)
            .then(resp => {return resp.blob()})
            .then(blob => {
                const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                const a = document.createElement('a');
                a.style.display = 'none';
                a.href = url;
                a.download = 'file_name';
                document.body.appendChild(a);
                a.click();
                window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url)
            })
        } else {
            // What do I put here to retry the fetch to /printStateAJX?id=
            return recursiveFunc(canID)
        }
    })    
}
```

Assuming the rest of the code is correct, this should work.